# My Python code keeps returning different errors when i run it

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am creating a small web scraping program in Python that takes GPU information from *newegg.com* and notes down all of the prices.
As of now, I have not implemented the spreadsheet as every time I run it, I get one of 2 errors.

The code is below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import numpy as np

myURL = "https://www.newegg.com/global/uk/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=-1&IsNodeId=1&Description=graphics%20card&bop=And&PageSize=96&order=BESTMATCH" # defining my url as a variable

uClient = uReq(myURL) #opening the connection
page_html = uClient.read() # getting html
uClient.close() # closing the client

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") # html parsing

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"item-container"}) #get all 
item containers/product

container = containers[0]

count = 0

for container in containers:

    print(count)

    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]# get the brand of the card
    if brand == None:
        print("N/A")
    else:
        print(brand)

    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class", "item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text # getting the product name
    if product_name == None:
        print("N/A")
    else:
        print(product_name)

    price1 = container.find("div",{"class":"item-action"})
    price1 = price1.ul
    price2 = price1.find("li", {"class": "price-current"}).contents #defining the product price
    if not price2:
        print("N/A")
    else:
        print(price2[2])
        print(price2[3].text)
        print(price2[4].text) 

    print()
    count+=1
```

The errors say the following:

1. > Traceback (most recent call last):
   >   File "C:/Users/Ethan Price/Desktop/test.py", line 23, in 
   >   brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]# get the brand of the card
   >   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
2. > Traceback (most recent call last):
   >   File "C:/Users/Ethan Price/Desktop/test.py", line 43, in 
   >   print(price2[2])
   >   IndexError: list index out of range

In trying to fix it, I tried to turn the list into an array and tried changing the if statements.

Comment: You need to verify tags and elements exist before accessing them, not checking for None after . Error handling is more important than perfect functionality

Answer (score 2):

Both error messages mean that some element you expect to see doesn't exist. The first is complaining that `container.div.div.a.img` is `None` when you try to subscript it (and `None`s can't be subscripted, for obvious reasons). The other is complaining that the list `price2` isn't as long as you think it is, so `price2[2]` is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

First error, check the image and its title tag exists

```
brand = None
# might want to check there is even an anchor tag 
_img = container.div.div.a.img
if _img:
    brand = _img["title"]
```

Second, check the length of the price listings

```
If 2 <= len(price2) <= 5:
    for p in price2[2:]
        print(p)
```